# Getting URL Contents with IP and Address Only

Tags: php, url, get, header, response

I am trying to create a website previewer in PHP to share with people.

So I want to have a service that will allow me to get the contents of a website but without changing the domain names DNS.

So using just the website URL and the IP address of the server.

I read on here someone said do something like this...

```
$s=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP); 
socket_connect($s,'68.233.243.63',80);
socket_send($s,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.domainname.com\r\n\r\n",1000,0);
socket_recv($s, $buf, 100000,0);
socket_close($s);
echo $buf;
```

But I cannot get it to work. I get 400 Bad Request.

Please can someone write a short test script to help me with this part of the application.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it's the domain you are trying to connect to. I receive a 200 OK while trying to connect to a HTTP domain.

Comment: This is just an example. I want to pass a server URL and a website name and then retrieve the contents. I have managed to get a 200 response using CURL but its the server configuration page you get in CPanel. Something doesn't seem to get passed.

Comment: I basically want to simulate a hosts file change to enable website previewing functionality